# Show start and end time for each User ID respectively

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I am running a `foreach` loop on each `UserId` but for some reason... In my `xml`, only one `userId` is being displayed along with all the start time and end time for all `userIds`. I need it to show `start` and `end` time for each `userId` respectively.

So it looks like this:

```
User2
Start
End
Start
End
Start
End
```

It needs to looks like this:

```
User1
Start
End
Start
End

User2
Start
End
```

My code:

```
foreach (String userId in request.Users) // request.Users is a Array of UserId's 
{
    List<UserModel> result = // I am making my DataAccess Layer call here.
    UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
    record.UserId = userId;
    record.TimePeriodList = new List<TimePeriod>();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i += 2)
    {
        TimePeriod timeData = new TimePeriod();
        timeData.StartTime = result[i].TimeDate;
        // if result count is an odd number and this is the last iteration for the UserId
        if (((result.Count & 1) == 1) && (i == result.Count))
            {
                timeData.EndTime = result[i + 1].TimeDate;
            }
            record.TimePeriodList.Add(timeData);
        }
        response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();
        response.UserRecordList.Add(record);
}

public class GetUserResponse
{
    private List<UserRecord> userRecordList;

    public List<UserRecord> UserRecordList
    {
        get { return userRecordList; }
        set { userRecordList = value; }
    }
}

public class UserRecord
{
    private string userId;
    private List<TimePeriod> timePeriodList;

    public string UserId
    {
        get { return userId; }
        set { userId = value; }
    }

    public List<TimePeriod> TimePeriodList
    {
        get { return timePeriodList; }
        set { timePeriodList = value; }
    }
}

public class TimePeriod
{
    private DateTime startTime;
    private DateTime endTime;

    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return startTime; }
        set { startTime = value; }
    }

    public DateTime EndTime
    {
        get { return endTime; }
        set { endTime = value; }
    }
}
```

My data returned from `DataAccess` layer looks like this:

```
UserId    Time        EventType
Test1   xx-xx-xxxx   Start
Test1   xx-xx-xxxx   End
Test2   xx-xx-xxxx   Start
```

So if there is an odd number then the End time for that `User` is `DateTime.MinValue` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you step through your program, noting the state of your variables you can easy spot the bug. Your code almost works because you get results back. The only result you see to get is the last user...

Let's look at your loop:

```
// you have created a response object here which I had to infer
var response = new GetUserResponse();  // added so my explanation makes sense

foreach (String userId in request.Users) // request.Users is a Array of UserId's 
{
    List<UserModel> result = // I am making my DataAccess Layer call here.
    UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
    // removed stuff that already works
    response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();
    response.UserRecordList.Add(record);
}
```

`request.Users` has two items, Test1 and Test2. Put a break point on the foreach loop and start debugging.

If we step into the foreach loop this the state:

```
response = instance1 of GetUserResponse
response.UserRecordList = null;
userId = test1
```

If we step until the line `response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();` this is the state:

```
response = instance1 of GetUserResponse
response.UserRecordList = null;
userId = test1
record = instance1 of UserRecord with values in its fields
```

When we step over the next line the state becomes

```
response.UserRecordList = new instance of List<UserRecord>(); // list1
```

and after the last line in the loop our state is

```
response.UserRecordList.Length = 1
```

Now we fetch the next item from the array so `userId` becomes test2.
Let's run until previous to last line again, until now UserRecordList still has the 1 UserRecord but if we step over that line, a **NEW** instance is created, I refer to that as list2:

```
response.UserRecordList = new instance of List<UserRecord>(); // list2
```

By this step the previous list1 is no longer referenced and will be garbage collected later on. In the last line the UserRecord for test2 is added and then we are done.

Obviously the line that creates a List of UserRecords shouldn't be inside the foreach loop.

The fix is rather easy

```
var response = new GetUserResponse();  // added so my explanation makes sense
response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>(); // init List once

foreach (String userId in request.Users) // request.Users is a Array of UserId's 
{
    List<UserModel> result = // I am making my DataAccess Layer call here.
    UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
    // removed stuff that already works
    // don't init the UserRecordList here, it is done at the start of the loop.
    response.UserRecordList.Add(record);
}
```